If $r,s,t$ are prime numbers and $p,q$ are the positive integers such that $lcm(p,q)=r^2t^4s^2$
If $r,s,t$ are prime numbers and $p,q$ are the positive integers such that $lcm(p,q)=r^2t^4s^2$. Then number of ordered pair $(p,q)$ is/are
My Understanding: I know how to solve this problem. Let $p=r^{a_{1}}t^{b_{1}}s^{c_{1}}$ and $q=r^{a_{2}}t^{b_{2}}s^{c_{2}}$
Also $\max\{a_{1},a_{2}\}=2$ which has four cases $\{(2,0), (0,2), (1,2), (2,1), (2,2)\}$
Similary $\max\{b_{1},b_{2}\}=4$ has $9$ cases and $\max\{c_{1},c_{2}\}=2$ has $5$ cases again. So final answer is $5\cdot 9\cdot 5=225$.
But my doubt is what about the question when this case work is long for example $lcm(p,q,r,s)=2^3\cdot3^9 \cdot 5^2 \cdot 7^4 \cdot 11^{3}$
In this case If I take $p=2^{a_{1}}3^{b_{1}}5^{c_{1}}7^{d_{1}}11^{e_{1}}$ , $q=2^{a_{2}}3^{b_{2}}5^{c_{2}}7^{d_{2}}11^{e_{2}}$, $r=2^{a_{3}}3^{b_{3}}5^{c_{3}}7^{d_{3}}11^{e_{3}}$, $s=2^{a_{4}}3^{b_{4}}5^{c_{4}}7^{d_{4}}11^{e_{4}}$
Now $\max\{a_{1}, a_{2},a_{3},a_{4}\}=3$ but involve lots of cases. So is there any easy method any one of you know to calculate $\max\{a_{1}, a_{2},a_{3},a_{4}\}=3$?
$\DeclareMathOperator{\LCM}{LCM}$
Same question has been asked here The lcm of $p,q$ is $r^2t^4s^2$ where $p,q,r,s,t$ are natural numbers. Find the number of ordered pairs $(p,q)$.

In your more complicated example  you have a similar issue over the maximum power, so let's concentrate on that.

The number of ways of having $k$ non-negative integers where none of them exceed $a$ is $(a+1)^k$
The number of ways of having $k$ non-negative integers where none of them exceed $a-1$ is $a^k$
So the number of ways of having $k$ non-negative integers where their maximum is $a$ is  $(a+1)^k-a^k$

Here $k=4$ so the answer is $$(4^4-3^4)(10^4-9^4)(3^4-2^4)(5^4-4^4)(4^4-3^4)= 2526085209375$$ ways of finding $(p,q,r,s)$ satisfying $\operatorname{lcm}(p,q,r,s)=2^3\cdot3^9 \cdot 5^2 \cdot 7^4 \cdot 11^{3}$.

If you want to find the $n$-tuples $(a_j)_{j=1}^n$ such that $[(a_j)_{j=1}^n]=\prod_{i=1}^k p_i^{c_i}$, you have an independent choice for every prime $p_i$. In particular if we put $a_j=\prod_{i=1}^k p_i^{a_{j,i}}$ the condition translates to $\max_{j}(a_{j,i})=c_i$ for all $i$. For a fixed $i$ you have $(c_i+1)^n-c_i^n$ choices (the complementary is the set of $n$-tuples $(a_{j,i})_{j=1}^n$ where all the terms are less than $c_i$), so the answer is
$$\prod_{i=1}^k ((c_i+1)^n-c_i^n).$$

but i want it for four elements or more

@mathophile Sorry, I edited the answer.
